# Melhor forma de criar relatorio de cliques (PHP MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, relatório, log

Estou montando um sistema do mercado imobiliario em que incorporadoras podem ver os terrenos disponíveis para construção. Aí quero registrar os cliques que cada incorporadora dá em qualquer terreno para depois eu puxar relatorios dos mais clicados, quais terrenos a incorporadora está interessada, etc.

Pensei em ir inserindo as informações em uma tabela mysql:

```
id|id-incorporadora|id-terreno|hora-do-clique
1 |   276          |   501    |2018-02-02 15:12:10
```

Mas acho que pode acabar ficando uma tabela muito grande, pois temos centenas de terrenos e centenas de incorporadoras.

Há alguma outra forma de se fazer isso, sem que fique tão pesado?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa pensar no nível de detalhe que quer, qual a utilidade e qualidade da informação para você.

Qual é o critério de análise que você precisará no final, o quanto essa informação tem que ser analítica e sintético para que isso aconteça.

---

Precisa questionar o máximo possível:

Qual a utilidade de saber quantas vezes no dia, ou na semana, a data e hora !?

Se nenhuma, beleza, então faço por mês para ter noção se eles estão de olho no terreno !?

Ah também não... então só faz por quantidade de cliques no total... e assim vai...

Por ex.: se eu fosse fazer isso, eu faria um acumulado mês x terreno ao invés de clique por clique, assim atenderia meu critério nem sintético nem analítico.

---

Não, eu quero realmente bem analítico.

Aí o foco é em performance no banco, principalmente para escrita, já que colocou que será grande a movimentação.

Ou até usar um Google Analytics, ou outras ferramentas do tipo.

---

> tem que ser bem analítico, porque queremos por exemplo: Incorporadora
>   A clicou 20 vezes no terreno X, e 15 vezes no terreno Y. E o contrário
>   também, o terreno X foi clicado pela incorporadora A, B e C... –
>   Leandro Teraoka

Por incorporadora sim... mas você precisa chegar ao nível de saber qual o dia e hora de cada clique ? ou se tivesse um resumo semanal, serviria ? Um resumo de incorporadora x terreno x cliques, entendeu ?

Por exemplo, semanal:

Você determinaria quando a semana tem início (ex domingo) então de domingo a sábado, você irá acumular cliques separando incorporadora x terreno x qtd_cliques... então se você tem 20 incorporadoras, 100 terrenos, no máximo seriam 2.000 registro, se todas incorporadoras clicarem em todos os terrenos. Mas se elas clicarem em todos os terrenos 5x, seriam ainda os 2.000, já sendo clique por clique, iram para 10.000.

Comment: tem que ser bem analítico, porque queremos por exemplo: Incorporadora A clicou 20 vezes no terreno X, e 15 vezes no terreno Y. E o contrário também, o terreno X foi clicado pela incorporadora A, B e C...

Comment: Editei a resposta, porque ficou muito grande para por nos comentários.

Comment: Relamente por hora foi um exagero...rs, mas preciso por dia, vc me deu uma luza já, faria por exemplo 20/02/2018 incorporadora X, 10 cliques, isso ne?

Comment: Exatamente..  mas faltou o terreno ! rs   `DATA | INCORPORADORA | TERRENO | CLIQUES`... Claro que, isso vai te dificultar no sistema, pois agora o método que só fazia inclusão, agora precisa fazer pesquisa, e a partir dela, incluir ou alterar (insert ou update).